# Check if Realm object already exists

Tags: objective-c, realm

I have a Realm object called `Restaurant`in my app. This `Restaurant` object has lots of `Table` objects connected to it. If I save on, it looks like this:

```
Restaurant *restaurant = [[Restaurant alloc] init];
restaurant.url = [_userData url];
restaurant.type = [_userData kind];

for (int i = 0; i < [[_userData tables] count]; i++) {
    Input  *input = [[_userData tables] objectAtIndex:i];
    Table *table = [[Table alloc] init];

    table.title = input.title;
    table.seats = input.seats;
    table.type = input.type;

    [restaurant.tables addObject:table];
}

RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
config.fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[Preferences getRealmPath]];
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:config error:nil];

[realm beginWriteTransaction];
[realm addObject:restaurant];
[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

Now, what I want is that when a restaurant is added, but it already exists in that configuration, it's not stored. But when the same restaurant is added, but *something* is different - even if it's the amount of seats at 1 table - it should be added. What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realm supports something called [primary keys](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#primary-keys), which seem like a good fit for your problem.

A primary key is a unique identifier for an Realm object; it can be an integer or a string. In your case, you might use the URL as the primary key (if each restaurant is indeed associated with only one URL), or add a new property to serve as the primary key (perhaps a `name` field).

You can then use the `addOrUpdateObject:` method instead of the `addObject:` method. This method only works for object types with primary keys.

In your case, assuming you set up a primary key for your `Restaurant` model type, Realm would do one of the following:

- If the `Restaurant` was previously added to the Realm and has not changed relative to your new model, nothing will change.
- If the `Restaurant` was previously added to the Realm but your model has since changed, the existing model in the Realm will be updated.
- If the `Restaurant` wasn't previously added to the Realm, it will be added.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well, I know about primary keys and I considered them. *But*, the user can input the data, so there might be multiple instances of a restaurant, where only a table has changed. All of these should be stored. It shouldn't be stored when it's a complete 1 to 1 match.

Comment: In that case, you probably want to [query](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#filtering) on your Realm for all `Restaurant`s that have the URL, type, and number of tables as the new `Restaurant` you want to add. If the `Results` of that query is empty, you can just add in the new model. Otherwise, you can iterate through the `Table`s in each result and check for equality (you probably want to override `isEqual:` on that class); if none of the results have identical tables to your model you know you can add it.

Comment: That's quite resource intensive, isn't it. I'd really like to know if there isn't a better way.

Comment: I'm afraid not, sorry. Realm is designed for the primary key use case I outlined above, not for checking and filtering models based on equality.

Answer (score 1):

Update to this: You no longer need to have different syntax when adding. Make sure a primary key exists and Realm will do the rest in terms of updating. [Link](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#objects-with-primary-keys)

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to create a primary key that hashes the value. i.e. create a hash from the data that is reasonably unique. Hash the restaurant name and table names for instance.

Then you would have to have buckets for each hash value which would contain the restaurants that hit it.

If a newly entered restaurant has no existing hash, it can simply be added to the bucket, otherwise a check to see if it matches an existing restaurant in the bucket is needed to test for uniqueness.